# How return copy from .find JS?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
let a =  this.menu.getMenuItems().find((item) => item.$entityType === val);
let b = Object.assign({}, a);

this.dictChildren = b.children.map((item) => {
});
```

First I try to find element in array then create copy.

After I attempted to modify found element using `map()`, despite

```
 let b = Object.assign({}, a);
```

It modifies original array.

How map only copied object b?

Comment: You need to **deep copy** the object.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: NinaScholz conveniently linked the duplicate that explains how to do that in the most efficient way, you should check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` makes a shallow copy and not a deep copy.